# find java cache directory - dynamically

Tags: java, caching, applet, java-web-start

Is there some way how to find the java cache directory programatically?

Normaly it is located in directory like this:

```
System.getProperty("user.home") + someMiddleDir + "/Sun/Java/Deployment/cache/" +
    versionCode;
```

which resolves on Windows Vista into `"c:/Users/userId/AppData/LocalLow/Sun/Java/Deployment/cache/6.0"`

But I would need to find it in some more dynamic/precise way (minimum hardcoded code/path).

Comment: For the first parth of your string, (home + middle dir), you can check the `%APPDATA%` environment variable.

Comment: `APPDATA` returns "C:\Users\userId\AppData\Roaming" so it's not absolutely correct as instead of "Roaming" there should be "LocalLow", but thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this:

com.sun.deploy.config.Config.getCacheDirectory()

one good friend told me about this little nasty method :)

Comment: This function does not function anymore in java 11

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution is to read the system property `deployment.user.cachedir`. I tested this with Java 8 and 9, both work in my case.

```
System.getProperty("deployment.user.cachedir")
```

Comment: Not working in Java 15.

Comment: I'm not surprised: Oracle does not include Web Start in Java SE 11 and later.